# Can I block based on MAC address?

Tags: network, http, webserver, attack-prevention, mac-address

If I block an IP, the attacker can work around the block by taking a new IP or use a proxy. Is it possible to make a ban based on MAC address? I want to block at the webserver level so that unwanted users don't create unnecessary traffic to the site.

Is the MAC address sent as a part of HTTP request?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about blocking HTTP requests at the web server? filtering access to a wifi point? other kind of networking? The question is not very clear.

Comment: @Avid: Yes HTTP Request at the web server

Comment: You can block based on the MAC address, but I can't imagine how that would help you. The MAC address would be that of your own router. MAC addresses are a LAN thing, not an Internet thing.

Comment: @fabianhjr : Done :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the MAC Address of the original sender (the actual client and not the last hop) isn't included in any of the network packet headers. Though, you might want to check: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Answer (score 26):

**In short**, the answer is **no**, you usually can't block based on MAC address. And if you could, it would be useless. To understand why, you must know a thing or two about how the internet works.

Communication between devices is commonly done via the [Ethernet protocol (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet), and despite the source and destination being identified by IP, actual communication is done per MAC. Imagine the following network:

[image]

If the client wants to send a packet to the server, it first checks whether the server is in the same subnet. Nope, the server has a 10.x IP, and the client an 192.168.x IP. The client then sends it to their router, R1, in the hope that it will be able to forward it to the destination. The packet contains:

```
Source IP:       192.168.1.100     (belongs to: Client)
Destination IP:  10.1.1.1          (belongs to: Server)
Source MAC:      01:01:01:02:02:02 (belongs to: Client)
Destination MAC: 02:01:01:02:02:02 (belongs to: R1)
```

Then `R1` is like "Oh, that IP is somewhere on the internet". It changes the source IP to the public IP (so that the server can send a packet back), and forwards it to R2. The packet now contains:

```
Source IP:       172.16.1.1        (public IP from R1)
Destination IP:  10.1.1.1          (belongs to: Server)
Source MAC:      02:01:01:02:02:02 (belongs to: R1)
Destination MAC: 03:01:01:02:02:02 (belongs to: R2)
```

As you can see, the destination IP doesn't change, but the MAC addresses changes every time it gets forwarded (by a router) based on which router it is forwarded to and which router it came from.

Moving forward, `R2` will not tamper with any of the IPs like `R1` did because it is not a NAT router (like most consumers have). `R2` will merely forward the packet.

In the end, the server will only be able to see the MAC address from R3. For the communication to work, that's all it needs to know besides the original IP from `R1`. (When a reply packet comes back at `R1`, other things make sure the packet finds its way to the client.) If you want to know why not all communication is simply MAC-based, have a look at [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/410626/why-couldnt-mac-addresses-be-used-instead-of-ipv46-for-networking).

**One exception to this** is when the client is inside the same LAN as the server. As I mentioned, the client first compares the IP subnet of itself and the destination. If it's the same (e.g. 192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.44, when on a /24 subnet), the communication is based on MAC address. The client will broadcast a message on the LAN, asking for the MAC belonging to the server's IP, and then send it to that MAC. The packet will still contain the destination IP, but there is no router between the two. (There may be, but then it will be acting as a switch or hub, not as router.) But this is probably not the scenario you had in mind.

**If you could determine the MAC,** that would be a pretty big privacy violation. Since your MAC address arguably identifies you uniquely on the globe, advertising networks would have no problem tracking you, also without tracking cookie or any other methods.

**Blocking an attacker by MAC would be the same as blocking him/her by cookie** because it is controlled by the client. Currently it's almost never changed because there is almost never a reason to, but if you could determine and block an attacker by MAC, they could simply change it. An IP addresses must be globally recognized in order to be routable, but a MAC doesn't have this issue.

Also, an attacker could block clients whose MAC they know by spoofing that MAC address and then triggering the block. Whoever really uses that MAC address would be prohibited from using the service.

**Conclusion:** If it were possible it would be rather ineffective and while introducing a DoS vulnerability, but since you can't make the client send the MAC along with HTTP headers or something, it's just not possible outside the same LAN.

Answer (score 10):

Source MAC addresses (layer 2) are only going to show the [last router](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/networking/ip_routing.htm) to forward the packet.

Comment: As an addendum: sometimes ISP's are limiting user amount to one or several end points. Though, this can be easily bypassed by setting up internal router or, how @AviD has said, by changing MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what this question is referring to - blocking HTTP requests at the web server? filtering access to a wifi point? Firewalls and routing?

But regardless, whether you can or cannot block based on the MAC address, a better question is *should* you block.
And the simple answer is: **No**.

Simply put, MAC addresses can easily be changed and/or spoofed, and are completely in control of the enduser (okay, *almost* completely). So, there's no point in trying to implement any type of control based on that.

Comment: How can you change a MAC Address without changing the network card ?

Comment: @Geek - it is possible to change MAC address with software, that depends on OS. For example, in Windows there is a registry key that holds MAC address, on *nix is done via "ifconfig" command. However, some cards allows to change hardware address itself.

Comment: @Geek: Most network cards support manual setting of a spoofed address. I.e. "Managed Address". Also via OS settings, depending.

Answer (score -5):

yes you can. Use a mac access-list on a switch...

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps646/products_configuration_example09186a0080470c39.shtml

Comment: Read the question entirely. Your answer applies to a LAN, but you can't just block any MAC address in the world with this switch. Also, this has already been covered in my answer.