# Ban MAC address from website?

Tags: webserver, mac-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I block based on Mac Address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/can-i-block-based-on-mac-address)

I have a situation where I need to ban a MAC address from accessing my webserver. (Windows Web Server 2008 R2). Is this possible?

P.S. I know how easy it is to change a MAC address... I just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: @Rook Your comment is unhelpful other than making fun of the asker. People ask questions because they don't know the answer. It would have been just as easy to point him to an answer as it was to type that comment.

Comment: @Mark Beadles  ok than this clearly doesn't belong here.  It should be on yahoo answers or something.

Comment: I think the most important question here is: Why do you want to block by MAC address rather than anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this unless the host happened to be on the same local network - at each hop, [the router changes the MAC addressing](http://ask-leo.com/can_a_mac_address_be_traced.html).

Comment: ...  and you can spoof your mac address so this would never even remotely work, ever.

Comment: @Rook Of course. :) But the asker already stated this in his question, so I did not address it further.